# Show 404 when endpoint exists mongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, react-native

I keep getting a 404 when I am posting to a route. I am using MongoDB, express and React Native. I have created the Schema, actions and router.

The Schema is below:

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create Edible Schema
const EdiblesSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  price: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  strength: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
    purchasedLocation: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  effects: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  strain: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
});

module.exports = Edibles = mongoose.model("edibles", EdiblesSchema);
```

Then the post router is below:

```js
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const keys = require("../../config/keys");

// Load edibles model
const Edibles = require("../../models/edibles");

// @route POST api/users/edibles
// @desc Add an edible to the users collection
// @access Public

router.post ('/edibles', (req, res) => {
 if (res.status === 200) {
    const newEdible = new Edibles({
        name: req.body.name,
        price: req.body.price,
        strength: req.body.strength,
        strain: req.body.strain,
        purchasedLocation: req.body.purchasedLocation,
        effects: req.body.effects,
    })
    } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ email: "Thats not going to get you high" });
    } newEdible
        .save()
        .then( edibles => res.json(edibles))
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
});


module.exports = router;
```

Then the finale we have the handleSubmit to send the users info to the api endpoint.

```js
const handleSubmit = (response) => {
    console.log("EDIBLES", name, strength, price, effects, strain)
    dispatch(setEdible(payload))

    if (response === 200) {
        axios
          .post(edibleApi, payload)
        console.log("PAYLOAD", edibleApi, payload, setEdible)
        // navigation.navigate("Dashboard")
    } else {
        console.log("WRONG", edibleApi, payload, setEdible);
        console.log("userEdibles", userEdibles)
    }
}
```

I am really lost with this... Please help!

Comment: What is the value for `edibleApi`?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/users/edibles

Comment: Have you tried `POST` to  `localhost:3000/api/users/edibles` from somewhere else? e.g. Postman or `curl`?

Comment: Tried on Postman and I get a 404

Comment: So it's most likely your server then. I only see the `/edibles` part of the path in the code you posted. How was the `api/users/` part created?

Comment: Yes it is. It's all working and fine. The same way as the edibles part... With MongoDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was using the wrong endpoint. I worked this out by using the express-list-routes by adding it to my server.js file.
`const expressListRoutes = require('express-list-routes');`

const router = express.Router();

console.log("Now we cooking with gas", expressListRoutes(app, { prefix: '/api/v1' })))

That console.log must be added to the console.log that indicates if your server is running or not....